# Increasing sequence between [L,R] using Segment Tree

Tags: tree, segment

I have a series of numbers and for each query, I have to find the sum of all the numbers from L to R such that the numbers form an increasing sequence also it is important that I always choose L and R.
If such a subsequence is not possible I return -1!
I want to implement it using the Segment tree but is unable to know what to store in the Segment Tree.

(I have to start from L and If I get larger number than prev I have to take it. Also Largest number between L,r Must be R)

```
Example:
array 3 1 4 1 5
Q
(1 3)->Ans: 7(index 0,2)
(1 2)->Ans: -1(1>3)
(2 5)->Ans: 1+4+5
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with idea to for each element store the next node (1st node with greater value than itself on the right side) and then use binary jumping, lifting or whatever its called (you also need to store sum of elements during jumps)
`pair<int, int> jump[n][20]; // (next node, sum)`
You can find next node using max segment tree.
(if you need help just write)

Complexity:

O(nlogn + qlogn)

n - number of elements in the arra, q - number of queries